# CoAP and suburl

Tags: coap

When I put up a resource as for example "SERVER"
and client tries to reach SERVER/something

does it fail to reach the resource? or it reaches SERVER resource and gives extra parameters?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

- If it was a CON request the server responds with a 4.04 (Not Found) ACK [Figure 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7252#page-13);
- if it was a NON request the server responds with a 4.04 (Not Found) NON [Figure 23](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7252#page-110);